# ie memory release

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory

Here is the code which test in IE8:

```
var stack = [];
function test() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i++ < 100000) {
        stack[i] = {a: "some string"};
        delete stack[i];
    };
}
test();
```

This script only uses a little memory in IE. Windows task manager shows 29704K, But the next:

```
var stack = [];
function test() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i++ < 100000) {
        stack[i] = {a: "some string"};
    };
    i = 0;
    while(i++ < 100000) {
        delete stack[i];
    }
}
test();
```

It uses 54860K memory. I wander why or how to release the memory other way.

Appreciated for your help.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage? Do you mean that after `test()` has been invoked the available free memory has been reduced by the numbers you've shown - a memory _leak_? Or that memory is used while the function is running but then becomes available again afterwards? Note that `delete` will remove the property but that doesn't mean the object the property used to reference will be immediately garbage collected.

Comment: Those two example are running in two page, nothing else in that page. I got the memory after a few minutes they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking at the total browser memory use at the system level, then you may be looking at the maximum browser memory usage, not how much memory is actually in use.  Just because you free something up in the browser does not mean that the browser returns that memory to the OS.  That memory may be available for future reuse in the browser, but not returned yet to the OS.

Your second example will have a higher peak memory use than the first example because you fully populate the array before you then remove elements.  Thus, it would not be surprising if it shows a greater memory use at the system level because of the higher peak usage.  That doesn't mean that the higher amount of memory is still in use, just that the browser had to request more memory from the system in order to deal with the higher peak usage and the browser did not necessarily return the now unused memory back to the OS.  That memory will be in the browser's pool of free memory that can be used for future memory requests so it's not a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wait for a long time, but the browser doesn't release the memory to the OS after handle the full array.

Comment: @user1476272 - that is no surprise.  The browser may keep the memory for future use.  Run the same function again and the memory should not go up either at all or as much because some of that memory is being reused.

Comment: Yeah, I invoked test() too many times and the max memory was 89M. You are right. But it doesn't release the memory to the OS, that's a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1476272 - If IE isn't giving back the memory, then that's just the way it's designed - nothing we can do about it here.  Why exactly do you think it's a serious problem?  Windows has virtual memory so even if it's never used again and the rest of your apps use up the rest of the physical memory, then this unused memory will get swapped out of physical memory to disk and never be an impact again.  Also, 89M in the context of system memory of 2-3GB is not a very big deal (3-4%).